# Is there a way to change link text in CSS?

Tags: css

Is there a way to do this in CSS? To clarify I only have access to CSS and the HTML code is the one below. So I can't use span or any other tags surrounding the link text

From

```
<a href="something.com">example text</a>
```

To

```
<a href="something.com">something else</a>
```

Comment: Checkout the ::after and ::before pseudo elements. In combination with text-indent and fixed widths this could work out, even though its pretty hacky.

Comment: why would you want to do this with CSS? please elaborate on the context as changing content with CSS is a bit quirky

Comment: @Aziz anime list website (similar to IMDB, but for anime) is letting you customize CSS on your list. So I want to change the text in CSS because they don't let you change HTML

Comment: Link, please? Also I wouldn't recommend this if it is against the site rules

Comment: @Aziz it is the sites feature, so not against the rules, the site is myanimelist.net and to go to the css edit it is http://myanimelist.net/editprofile.php?go=stylepref&do=cssadv&id=402917

Comment: @dovla If someone's solution solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. For more info: [how does accepting an answer work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like this:

```css
body {
  /* just for demo */
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
}
a {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  /* collapse extra space */
}
a::before {
  content: "Now I'm This";
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 16px;
  /* reset font size */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.<a href="something.com">I was This</a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure CSS way is to make use of the pseudo selectors `:before` or `:after` and `content` property.

**Edit: Hide previous text without `<span>`**

```css
/* demo */
a { background:blue; text-align: center; color:#FFF; display:inline-block; padding:1em; }

/* hide original text */
a {
  position:relative;
  color:transparent;
}

/* new text with psuedo selector */
a:before {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  content: "something else";
  color:#FFF;
  z-index:1;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  font-size:initial;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">something</a>
```

**Explanation:**

- First, we hide original text by making the text color transparent.
- Then we add the new text with a pseudo selector that has a visible color (in my example, white)

Used `position: absolute` to make sure the new text is ABOVE the original.

Comment: I think it's nice answer now (Y)

Comment: Except for any surrounding text.

Comment: What do you mean by `surrounding text`? @Paulie_D

Comment: Put text before and after the link and, in your case you may get overlapping text if the new content is longer than the previous content.

Comment: oh you are right. I saw that on the OP's site the button has a fixed width so this might not be an issue? Overall, it is situational and thanks for clarifying :) @Paulie_D

Answer (score 0):

Changing content with CSS is a bit quirky

you can use javascript as follows :

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Another text"
```

```html
<a id="demo" href="something.com">example text</a>
```

Comment: OP asks for CSS only

Comment: I couldn't change it with css as he exactly needed

Comment: Microsmsm  see my answer

Comment: I need it in CSS only since in this situation HTML is not available

Comment: But it's not exactly as he asks @dippas